# Setting up Acronym on IEEEtran Class Documemt

Tags: bibliographies, acronyms, ieeetran

I am looking for a way to setup acronym list such that, on first reference the full name will be listed and the acronym in brackets. From thereon, future reference to the acronym will only give the abbreviated form.

For example, "This is an Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) article. ACM is very popular in computer science."

For both reference to ACM above, I would refer it just like `cite`, say \abr{ACM}. So the above would be written in tex file as: "This is an Association for \abr{ACM} article. \abr{ACM} is very popular in computer science."

Similar to Bibliography, what ACM stands for would be mentioned somewhere.

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package is widely used for this kind of things.

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[shortcuts,acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries % generates the acronym list

\newacronym{acm}{ACM}{Association for Computing Machinery}

\begin{document}

This is an \ac{acm} article. \ac{acm} is very popular in computer science.

\printglossaries % prints the acronym list

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

To generate the output you can choose different methods. Supposing that your file is called `myfile.tex`, you can run

1. If you have [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arara) installed

   > arara myfile
2. If not, but you have Perl installed

   > pdflatex myfile
   >
   > makeglossaries myfile
   >
   > pdflatex myfile
   >
   > pdflatex myfile
3. If you don't have either `arara` or Perl

   > pdflatex myfile
   >
   > makeindex.exe -s myfile.ist -t myfile.alg -o myfile.acr myfile.acn
   >
   > pdflatex myfile
   >
   > pdflatex myfile

Comment: Working as per requirement. However, the glossary list is not printed. Not sure if it's not printed for the same reason I mentioned earlier. Please look at the comment I left for Harish Kumar.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Which of the ways I mentioned are you using for compiling it?

Comment: I am using TexMaker/MixTex on windows, so not sure which step applies. I think, the third one sounds closest to what I want, but haven't tried it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `acro` package that provides numerous options.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{acro}

% class `abbrev': abbreviations:

% class `nomencl': nomenclature
\DeclareAcronym{acm}{
  short = ACM ,
  long  = Association for Computing Machinery ,
  sort  = A ,
}

\begin{document}

\ac{acm}, is an abbreviation. \Ac{acm} is an association.

\printacronyms    %% put this where you want the list of abbreviations

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using it using TexMaker/MikTex and I got error saying the translations.sty not found. Should this not install automatically. TexMaker did download bunch of packages.

Comment: I manually added translations.sty and it appears to do what I want. Although nothing is listed after acronyms, I am good for now.